# Add button to dynamically added android Supportmapfragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am adding SupportMapFragment programmatically to my main activity.
I am able to add it but i need a edit text and a button also to be displayed at the top of the map.
I have created a separate layout for my map fragment which i add programmatically inside my main activity. But i get a NPE saying "Unable to resume activity"

Please help me.
Here is my code . MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
GoogleMap googleMap;
String lat;
String provider;
protected double latitude,longitude;
protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;
private ImageView mImage;

List<Marker> markerslist = new ArrayList<Marker>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    //add a fragment
    MapFragmentActivity mapFragment = new MapFragmentActivity();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.appfragment, mapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.eemaView);
    mImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("inside on click eema");
            EnterpriseFragment entFragment = new EnterpriseFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTrans = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTrans.replace(R.id.appfragment, entFragment);
            fragmentTrans.commit();
        }
    });
    mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.deviationView);
    mImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("inside on click deviation");
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            //add a fragment
            MapFragmentActivity mapFragment = new MapFragmentActivity();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.appfragment, mapFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my fragment class

```
public class MapFragmentActivity extends SupportMapFragment implements LocationListener{

protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
GoogleMap googleMap;
String lat;
String provider;
protected double latitude,longitude;
protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;
List<Marker> markerslist = new ArrayList<Marker>();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapfragmentlayout, container, false);

}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    googleMap = this.getMap();
    if (googleMap != null) {
        //Your initialization code goes here
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);

        // Getting reference to btn_find of the layout activity_main
        //Button btn_find = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_find);

        // Defining button click event listener for the find button
        View.OnClickListener findClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Getting reference to EditText to get the user input location
                EditText etLocation = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.et_location);

                // Getting user input location
                String location = etLocation.getText().toString();

                if(location!=null && !location.equals("")){

                    for(Marker m : markerslist) {
                        System.out.println("Marker size is "+markerslist.size());
                        System.out.println("Title is "+m.getSnippet());
                        System.out.println("Position is "+((LatLng)(m.getPosition())).latitude);
                        if(location.equals(m.getSnippet())) {
                            // do something with the marker
                            LatLng latLng = m.getPosition();
                            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
                            break; // stop the loop
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        };

        // Setting button click event listener for the find button
        //btn_find.setOnClickListener(findClickListener);


        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {


                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.site_info_window, null);

                List<String> qfList = JSONReader.readQuickFixData(getActivity());
                ListView devLst = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.deviationList);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.simple_list_item_deviation,android.R.id.text1,qfList);
                devLst.setAdapter(adapter);
                return v;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my fragment layout xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_find"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Find"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_location"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Enter Site ID"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_find" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My main layout xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WEM App"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/appfragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hsview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/deviationView"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/sema_icon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/eemaView"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/eema_icon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/siteView"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/sema_icon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/alertsView"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/eema_icon" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have something special in your lifecycle methods (onPause(), onResume() etc)?

Comment: No I  am not using any of those lifecycle methods.I just have oncreateView and onActivityCreated.If i remove oncreateView  i do not see any error and map gets displayed but  the layout xml i have created does not get loaded.I need a way to inflate  that layout xml having the button. I do have overridden methods from the inteface i have implemented LocationListener!

Comment: @Nanda: May I know wt is R.id.appfragment?

Comment: R.id.appfragment is a LinearLayout inside main layout xml where i am displaying my fragment contents.Below that LinearLayout i display a list of buttons inside horizontal scroll view on click on each i call different fragemnts.

Comment: @Nanda: Check my answer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure u r using `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` and `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;`

Make changes as below -

change `public class MapFragmentActivity extends SupportMapFragment`

to `public class MapFragmentActivity extends Fragment` keep rest as it is.

Comment: No Luck I still get an NPE!ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.wipro.wemdroidapp/com.abc.wemdroidapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2841)

Comment: i read in some other posts that i cannot override oncreateView() if i extend  SupportMapFragment. But if that is the case is it possible to have my own xml layout for the fragment? I have changed the root tag in the above fragment layout xml to framelayout.

Comment: @Nanda: can u explain wt u need to achieve?

Comment: Thanks a million!! It worked! Superb solution! You made it look so easy! :)